# Given unlimited time to solve a technical challenge at home and allowed to use the Internet, for interview

Tags: interviewing, test

I'm new to professional software development for a company. I had an interview, and it went well. They emailed me a technical challenge with a few different parts. They said there were no time limits, it's open book, and I can use the Internet. I have a tendency to overthink things and was wondering, in theory this means I can learn anything I don't know so I can answer the questions fully and correctly. Am I looking at it the right way?

One of the questions was to implement a responsive horizontal navigation bar for a website. I can't do this without consulting references. But it's not hard to find fully worked examples and their source code online. I would consider just copying them cheating, but does it really make a difference if I understand them and then copy the code? Obviously I wouldn't get someone else to do it for me and would only use existing examples on websites like W3Schools.

Comment: This sounds awfully like work-for-free maskerading as a technical test... Be wary

Comment: @HorusKol: If there are worked examples already online, this seems like a typical academic exercise. If anything, it will be too bland and theory-based to relate directly to work.

Comment: @HorusKol can't you protect yourself as long as you've not signed anything? Legally speaking the code is yours, no matter the context.

Comment: Just make sure you don't take a month to do. There was a similar question some time ago, I'm pretty sure they never contacted the candidate when he took a month to make it pretty.

Comment: @PierreArlaud yes, but then you'd have to engage a lawyer and assert your ownership in court. A company that use "tests" for work would bank on you just walking away from the fight. But I'm not saying this is the case - but just be wary.

Comment: Then it's the approach that counts. Choose your tools wisely and be prepared to explain your choices.

Comment: Why not ask the company?

Comment: The main reason I'd not _just_ copy a working example is that at a subsequent interview they may ask you to just "_alter what you did last week_" to add a feature, or ask you to explain how it works.

Comment: At work, our best people use phrases like "Google/StackOverflow is my mentor."  Those are our best people.  It would be expected that a less experienced person do the same, not to try to be above that and do it on their own.

Comment: @Иво Недев Agreed.  If I was setting this I'd be grading on quality of answer vs time taken and picking the best combination.  SO OP must NOT overthink - they need to get back a good response within a very short time (no more than a day or two) - after a week I'd be assessing the responses and making an offer.

Comment: This is how software developers work, on the whole. So this sounds like a reasonable way to assess your ability to do the job. Although, as has been noted, it does sound like work for free, so be careful of the scope here. If it's more than a weeks work, just tell them outright that this feels like a scam, and walk.

Comment: The edits seem to have removed the question from the title, leaving only the context... that is a serious regression in my opinion.

Comment: @HorusKol, I always find this "work-for-free" opinion regarding interviews pretentious. As someone who's interviewed candidates, I know that their response won't be production-worthy. I don't expect it to be. The candidate has no context, may be nervous, has no access to source control, can't view other code that may help, and can't work with the users to test the code. If I gave a candidate a homework assignment and they acted like I was asking them to "work-for-free", that'd tell me that they don't know about the SDLC. That's a red flag given I'm hiring someone to be a part of the SDLC.

Comment: @user2023861 I find extended "homework" tests like this pretentious - either they're trivial nonsense that can't reveal anything that a good technical discussion in a face-to-face can, or they're over-complicated and a waste of time for the candidate and employer (particularly the staff member who has to review the work). If you want to know how a developer fits in your SDLC, either get him in for a week or two (paid), or give him an offer with a probation.

Comment: @HorusKol, Neither of your solutions are tenable.  If I want to interview four employees, your approach would take 1-2 months just to identify a candidate.  If I interview all four and decide to offer the first one, I have to hope that that candidate hasn't accepted any offers in the previous 0.5 - 1.5 months.  Chances are, if I want to hire that candidate, someone else does too.  Not to mention that I'll be getting new-employee work for the whole time.  I'm sure the users and team leaders would love explaining business logic to new developers every 1-2 weeks.

Comment: @AJFaraday, "if it's more than a weeks work"? If it takes a week he definitely shouldn't do it. In fact it would be unreasonable from the company to ask for more than 2-3h of his time since he has no guarantee he will get the job. The company should devise the test so that it can be done within a short time while still allowing him to show his skills.

Comment: I would have to see the actual question(s) to know if they look fishy or not, but it sounds like they're probably testing your ability to find a solution given online resources. There's obviously a time limit, even if that's not stated, because they're not going to wait too long for a response. In my experience, a significant chunk of development is online research, every bit as important as writing code & testing.

Comment: @user2023861 sorry, that's not what I'm saying at all - I'm saying that the "homework" test is pointless - you should be able to get a good measure on their technical ability through discussion at the face-to-face interview. If you aren't, then you aren't interviewing right. And even if they "passed" the homework test, you still have to put the candidate on probation to make sure they work within your team - so what advantage does the test bring? - sorry, comments are not a great forum for getting into details... maybe make it a question (though I fear will be opinion-based answers)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

If I gave a developer a task such as 'Create a responsive horizontal nav bar', I'd be very disappointed if they spent hours creating it from scratch when there are so many viable and correct solutions already out there. You don't have time in the real world to create the perfect solution every time,

Comment: I agree, perhaps comment it so they can see that you understand all the facets

Comment: If I assign the task "create X" but instead you just copy and paste and turn in someone else's X, why shouldn't I be disappointed?

Comment: @Brandin because this isn't high school any more. Copying isn't bad (As long as you follow licences). Someone who takes something of the net and modifies it to do the just instead of spending 10 times that amount of time trying "re-invent the wheel" is more cost effective of companies.

Comment: @Snowlockk: I would note: copying is fine *as long as you have a minimum understanding of how the thing works*. Most notably, of how to use it correctly, what are its edge cases (if any), etc... do remember than once it's in your codebase, you're responsible for maintaining it.

Comment: @MatthieuM. In my experience what is on the net is very rarely a copy, paste and forget thing. Most times you need to modify it to fit what you want it to do. In the course of doing this you should you understand it.

Comment: @Snowlockk Agreed if the license is followed and everyone is on board with that. But the phrase "copy-and-paste" may disregard that.

Comment: @Snowlockk: That's my experience too, indeed. However the OP started their question with "I'm new to professional software development" so their level of experience is unknown and thus I'd rather err on the side of caution in the advice given; better elaborate too much than let misunderstandings creep in.

Comment: For the example given, my expectations would be like @Brandin 's for 'Create a responsive horizontal nav bar', but inline with yours for 'Create a page with a responsive horizontal nav bar'.  To me the former reads as an explicit request to make the nav bar, not just to find and reuse something from elsewhere.

Comment: I think this depends highly on what the intent of the exercise was.  Did they want to test if he could implement the bar, or did they want to test if he could code a functioning bar?  The two skills show very different things and would be used for different reasons.

Answer (score 83):

1. Pretend you're doing this for a real job
2. Be legal (i.e. educated on when attribution is necessary and follow licenses)

This naturally will involve pretty aggressive searching online and adapting full solutions. A full copy/paste is rarely what works in the real world even if it's often a good start.

"No time limits" may even be a hint of the form, "this will take you a very long time if you build things from scratch and mere minutes if you use StackOverflow."

Comment: point 2 is important

Comment: IMO the "unlimited time" is also a hint to "we're gonna ask how what you've choosen works, study it".

Comment: While this is good advice, I feel it's a bit too strong for the Software Development world - using sources from the web is pretty common practice - as long as it's not being ripped directly, there should be no problem.  That being said, that also depends on how the *interviewer* is 'grading' this project, so I'm not going to downvote this, on the grounds that someone doing the interview with little tech expertise *might* see a problem with direct copying (and really, it shouldn't be *entirely* copied anyway).  So I'd say, just be careful.

Comment: "No time limit"  can also be part of the test.  Do you find something, do some refactoring, maybe add some tests and deliver a good solution in a short time, or do you hand roll a gold plated solution that only you understand and takes days to build.  I know who I would hire.

Comment: @TheWanderingDevManager one of those things (shorter/better) is strictly better than the other, so of course.

Comment: @Zibbobz I almost never copy & paste code directly, and even when I do I often end up modifying it later anyway; there's almost always some variable names that I can improve or other minor modifications to make. But for adapted code, or even for a technique I learned from a particular source (without actually copying and pasting any code), I *always* provide attribution, even if it's just a link in a comment to a StackOverflow post.

Comment: Regarding point 2. Source code licensing is extremely complicated. I always leave a link for where I found it from and hope that covers me. I know the knee jerk reaction is "consult a lawyer" but consider this situation in context, it wouldn't make sense to pay a lawyer to ask if you're attributing the code right for one question in a technical interview.

Comment: [It is "Stack Overflow", not "StackOverflow"](http://stackoverflow.com/legal/trademark-guidance) (the last section, "Proper Use of the Stack Exchange Name"). Please edit your answer.

Answer (score 11):

If you are allowed to use the Internet, you're also expected to copy-and-paste from existing Internet sources. In fact, a well trained software engineer is also someone who can read somebody else's source code and modify it for custom use. Only inexperienced engineers would start from scratch when there's good existing alternative.

Obviously, the challenge is about how you would work if they hired you. Be smart, be efficient, modify existing solution but pay attribution and look at the license (GPL?).

Comment: "If you are allowed to use the Internet, you're also expected to copy-and-paste from existing Internet sources" - No.

Comment: Regarding licensing: it's a nightmare. Some of the websites I find code at have license models so complicated I can't understand them. It wouldn't make sense to hire a lawyer each time you find code on the internet, so what is one to do? I always link back to where I found it and hope that covers me.

Comment: Just find something that's uses the Apache, bsd, or MIT licenses and avoid GNU like the plague. Works for most situations. Also, most 'open' licenses are a lot more friendly if you simply 'use' them as opposed to digging into the code and tweaking it. Modern SO contributions are MIT: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271080/the-mit-license-clarity-on-using-code-on-stack-overflow-and-stack-exchange

Comment: @Jeutnarg Or use something licensed under the GPL (not LGPL) *on purpose* to keep the company from using it in their commercial/proprietary product...

Answer (score 8):

If the company conducting the test has half a clue, and you're called in for another interview afterwards, **you will be asked detailed questions about your work** and quite possibly to make modifications to it as well.

So yes, you can and probably should make use of sources on the Internet, just make sure **you understand how it works** (as in, can explain every line if needed) and that attribution/licensing is in order.

Answer (score 7):

As your hiring manager, I naturally want to assess your skill, and that includes your capability to re-use existing solutions, as well as your ability to think on the fly and to learn. I don't want employees who rush to meet a deadline, but give me low quality output - and on the other hand, I don't want employees who make awesome stuff, but take forever to do so. I need end-user quality and I need to meet reasonable deadlines, and this is one way to check if you fulfil both criteria. If you present a good solution in a reasonable timescale, regardless of the method, then you represent value for money as an employee.

The old adage holds true here: "**Fast, cheap, or good - pick two.**" They want to know which two you are.

If I were you, I'd try to stop overthinking it, and feel free to use any community resources and code snippets. This is what happens with real developers in real jobs, and the fact that it's an interview shouldn't sway your methodology. So long as you understand the code, the solution works, and you aren't doing anything inappropriate, illegal or immoral, then I don't personally see a problem.

As for what is inappropriate, illegal or immoral, the industry you are applying for may have security or ethics regulations which prevent certain types of code being used. Showing knowledge of these limitations and being aware of the morality of using publicly-available code snippets will only show your hiring manager what a thoughtful and considerate developer you are.

Comment: Hi, flith, just dropping in as part of the community review queue. Welcome to The Workplace SE! While I think your answer presents a good foundation for your answer, I personally would read it afterwards and think, "So I still don't know which two to choose." Not to say that you should dictate the questioner's choice, but perhaps give OP the choices that you would pick/have picked in the past to help bring some experiential wisdom to your answer? Or if you feel that that's too personal, perhaps a pros and cons of the combinations? (Cont'd.)

Comment: (Cont'd.) But this is just my two cents as part of the community review queue, so feel free to totally ignore my comments. We're just happy to have your help :). Thanks!

Comment: If he can't figure out the right one by himself, I'm not going to hire him ;) but joking aside, that's a fair point. I'll update my answer to include some personal commentary on which way I'd go.

Comment: @TeacherKSHuang: This answer points out that they are a personality which the manager wants to determine by a test. I would disagree with that and say that the adjective **responsive** tells the OP what it should be.

Comment: I had upvoted your comment, but just some actual textual feedback, good update!

Comment: @user3644640: not sure I follow you, *the adjective responsive tells the OP what it should be* - as far as I can tell, in the OP's question, the *responsive* refers to an implementation detail (responsive design that changes based on the browser's viewport size, for example) rather than any aspect of the developer's personality.

Comment: @flith: The word responsive says that it should do as you said, but also that it should minimise the use of resources. Also the unlimited time is a hint for it  to be done well. I can be overthinking and that is just the way how the manager speaks, but I see there an intention of checking that the OP notices those small things and delivers an implementation based on those.

Comment: @user3644640 the "responsive" is a tech term in web development.

Answer (score 6):

Whenever I am asked to complete a technical coding test, I always google the internet for answers and read through three or four examples. Then I ignore everything they did and write it my own way. Let me go into more detail for why this is necessary.

**Most of the answers you find on the internet are only going to be technically correct.**

For example, if you have a question about how to do X there are very likely multiple ways to do this regardless of what language or frameworks you are using. Some of these will be scalable - some will not. Some will use methods that are rightly deprecated (Eval!) and some will not. Some will be out of date for modern programming languages, and some will not.

Most answers will NOT work in a real-world situation. Are they quick solutions? Yes, but they are usually quick for a reason.

**With more then one way of doing something, you have a chance to demonstrate mastery, not just understanding.**

This is your chance to demonstrate the specific expertise you bring to the table by being able to demonstrate that you understand the different approaches and when to use which one. For example, I will sometimes provide TWO different solutions, with an explanation of which solution fits which situation.

"You didn't say if this code was meant to be re-useable, I usually assume reuse-ability, but the fast example is here. However, if this was something I was expecting to re-use, I would structure it like so."

**If you can Google a solution, expect that the interviewer can to.**

I know in the past when I have looked at coding samples submitted by prospective employees, I have put portions of their code into Google to see if they copied it from somewhere. Typically if the code is presented that way, with no explanations, I will reject the candidate outright. If they provide explanations, good on them.

It's important - if you use any other copied code or if you use a framework - to explain why you selected what you did, and not just include them outright. Otherwise the interviewee will simply assume you googled what was best and don't understand the nuances of what you selected.

**Interviewers should be more interested in your thought process then your technical skills.**

Frankly, anyone can google enough code and with a low level of skill, slap something together these days. Really good technical tests will require you to submit a repository history along with your submission to ensure that they can follow along with how you developed it. This is much harder to fake, and gives a much better idea of how the candidate came to the solutions that he came to.

Copying someone elses code gives them no reason to hire you over anyone else, and no insight into how your mind works and if you are a good meld for their existing team and company culture.

**Showing and explaining multiple approaches shows that you took the time to research the project, did not fire from the hip, and put care and consideration into even the most insignificant work that you do.**

This cannot be stressed enough - as a hiring manager I want candidates who know what they don't know and have the capability to learn. And as a candidate, I want a job where going the extra mile will be recognized and mean something. Taking extra care, providing additional information and coding samples shows the company want kind of a candidate you are AND gives you a chance to feel out what kind of company they are doing to be.

While copying and pasting might be the quick solution - companies that accept candidates who are just able to copy and past technical test answers quickly and easily are going to have a much poorer base programmer then companies that reject them, and probably aren't a place you are going to want to work at for very long.

Comment: How odd that the bottom two answers (at this writing) are, in my view, the most helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Slightly different background here but hopefully some overlap with your situation. The type of test we give to candidates isn't difficult but you're also unlikely to find an answer online as it requires a particular series of calculations to get to a particular number. Getting the right answer is great but the real challenge is to demonstrate that you can apply best practices (in the language of your choice). In terms of code there is no correct answer. We have certain general expectations but are also well aware that there are better developers than us out there.

All our candidates can program but not all supply code that demonstrates serious thought about the application, and anticipates having to work with a team of developers and testers or their code being run by end-users.

Things we like to see are:

- a correct understanding of the problem and a simple solution to it,
- tests (system, unit, even manual tests are better than nothing),
- comments,
- consistent coding conventions (naming, indentation, braces),
- making values configurable instead of hardcoding,
- no unused code,
- validation of inputs,
- helpful error handling,
- minimal repetition,
- encapsulation and other nice OO stuff (but only when it's genuinely useful to the situation at hand).

Bonuses are:

- Documentation,
- UI (as well as command line),
- support for debugging,
- detailed output beyond the specific value requested.

Answer (score 1):

Some large organisations have technical challenges that aren't just getting work for free. I know that Sky, in the UK, set a developer challenge (as I have been through their process).

Usually though, there is a deadline (albeit a loose one). I was asked to put the code on github and they then checked the code and in the interview, this work was extensively reviewed. The task took about 8 hours or so to do (but this was mainly because I added bells and whistles to make me look good).

Everything from naming, project structure to checkin comments and extra things (UI etc) were commented on.

You have to think "Why are they making me do this?". It could be a 2 bit company that want work for free, but it may also be a company that want to see how you approach a problem and how you go about doing your work.

You need to make sure you submit code that you are happy with (so therefore need understanding) and reflects how you work. When you submit code, add comments, even send a brief explanation of your approach and why you did it using X instead of Y. This is a good way (for you) to demonstrate knowledge without being in a pressure of an interview, so you should view it as a positive.